# Use solarized or similar in Ubuntu Server

Tags: command-line, server

It's possible to use [Solarized](https://github.com/altercation/ethanschoonover.com/blob/master/projects/solarized/README.md) color scheme (or similar) in a Ubuntu Server 14.04 CLI only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried this myself, but you should be able to change the color palette of the text mode by using the [`restorepalette`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/restorepalette.1.html) tool. From the man page:

> ```
> NAME
>    restorepalette - set the color palette for textmode.
>
> SYNOPSIS
>    restorepalette [filename]
>
> DESCRIPTION
>    restorepalette  without  arguments  sets the standard VGA palette. This
>    can be useful if it is somehow messed up.
>
>    With a filename argument a custom palette can be loaded (feature  added
>    by Charles Blake <chuckb@alice.wonderland.caltech.edu>).
>
>    This  allow  a  user  to  set up a file that looks like this one (These
>    color map definitions are the same as the default VGA ones.   Alter  to
>    suite  personal  tastes).  The  first column contains the number of the
>    color to set, then follow three integers in range 0  -  63  (lowest  to
>    highest intensity) for red, green, blue.
>
>            0  0  0  0   # black
>            1  0  0 42   # blue
>            2  0 42  0   # green
>            3  0 42 42   # cyan
>            4 42  0  0   # red
>            5 42  0 42   # magenta
>            6 42 21  0   # brown
>            7 42 42 42   # white
>            8 21 21 21   # bright black
>            9 21 21 63   # bright blue
>           10 21 63 21   # bright green
>           11 21 63 63   # bright cyan
>           12 63 21 21   # bright red
>           13 63 21 63   # bright magenta
>           14 63 63 21   # bright brown
>           15 63 63 63   # bright white
>
>    The  inline  comments  are  the only kind of allowed, as I use a little
>    fscanf(3) trick to get them. Blank lines are ok, but not  pure  comment
>    lines. See the comments in my code, also.
>
>    This allows people to set up custom palettes for use in virtual console
>    text modes. I use it all the time. When combined  with  a  color-syntax
>    editor  like jed-0.97+ or color-ls, etc., being able to choose your own
>    text-mode palette is quite a bonus. I set mine  up  via  restorepalette
>    /etc/palette  in  my  /etc/rc.   If  the  program  is given the correct
>    permissions, then individual users can have  restorepalette  ~/.palette
>    or  some  such  thing  in  their  shell  startup  files.  Of course, it
>    shouldn't be done when starting remote shells or when under X, so  some
>    kind of test that TERM is a virtual console is needed for that case.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

From:
https://acceptsocket.wordpress.com/2014/08/12/set-solarized-dark-as-default-color-scheme-for-linux-virtual-console/

```
if [ "$TERM" = "linux" ]; then
echo -en "\e]P0073642" #black
echo -en "\e]P8002b36" #brblack
echo -en "\e]P1dc322f" #red
echo -en "\e]P9cb4b16" #brred
echo -en "\e]P2859900" #green
echo -en "\e]PA586e75" #brgreen
echo -en "\e]P3b58900" #yellow
echo -en "\e]PB657b83" #bryellow
echo -en "\e]P4268bd2" #blue
echo -en "\e]PC839496" #brblue
echo -en "\e]P5d33682" #magenta
echo -en "\e]PD6c71c4" #brmagenta
echo -en "\e]P62aa198" #cyan
echo -en "\e]PE93a1a1" #brcyan
echo -en "\e]P7eee8d5" #white
echo -en "\e]PFfdf6e3" #brwhite
clear #for background artifacting
fi
```

I added this to my `.bashrc` file on Ubuntu 14.04.03 and it changed my virtual terminal to Solarized Dark